# Sqlite fetch from table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table named Text_Field which consists of a column named ID,

I have another table named Content which consists of a table named value,

I want to fetch those values of ID from the Text_Field table which are present in the value column of the Content and satisfying a said condition.

I know I can construct a query like this

```
SELECT ID 
FROM Text_Field 
WHERE ID IN (
    SELECT value 
    FROM CONTENT 
    WHERE USER='CURRENT_USER')
```

My only problem is that for some scenarios the value table might contain the ID inside a string

So the inner query might return something like

```
56789
12334
12348
Rtf(833405)
```

Now if my ID is 833405 it is present in the value column but the IN query would return false,

I tried

```
group_concat(value)
```

So that the inner query returns a single row which is a string,

```
56789,12334,12348,Rtf(833405)
```

I want to know that after group_concat can I use something as LIKE to satisfy my need 
Or is there some other way I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `exists` instead, with `like`:

```
SELECT t.ID 
FROM Text_Field t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM CONTENT c
              WHERE c.USER = 'CURRENT_USER' AND
                    (c.value = t.id OR 
                     c.value LIKE '%(' || t.id || ')%'
                    )
             );
```

Note:

Comment: Can he use `regexp` Gordon?

Comment: @Pokies . . . If the version of SQLite supports it, then yes.